# How to set a maximum date for date picker swift 4?

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I'm trying to set the maximum date to be 7 days ahead of the current date ( today's date).

```
datePicker.maximumDate =
```

Answer (score 5):

I've figured it out.

```
var sevenDaysfromNow: Date {
   return (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date(), options: [])!
}

datePicker.maximumDate = sevenDaysfromNow
```

Comment: You shouldn't use NSCalendar when coding in Swift 3. The equivalent Calendar method in Swift 3 you just have to remove the last parameter (options). `return Calendar.currentdate(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())!`

Comment: better than adding 7 days just add 1 week `Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: Date())!`

Comment: @LeoDabus, 7 days and 1 week are not necessary same thing in some calendars

Comment: @user28434 which calendar the week doesn't have 7 days?

Comment: @LeoDabus [Like those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars#Non-standard_weeks). I'm not sure that iOS SDK supports any of them by now, but there's no guarantee that there would be no support of some like those in the future. And there's no guarantee that `Calendar.current` wouldn't be one of them. So either set in days, or set specific calendar.

Comment: @user28434 just use a fixed calendar if that is a problem

Comment: @user28434 are they available in iOS? I don't think so. If you try to get weekday it will always return 1-7

Comment: @LeoDabus, `there's no guarantee that there would be no support of some like those in the future`. Anyways: It is bad to assume any relations between time units in `Calendar.current`, because it can be any calendar.

Comment: Believe me this is a totally unnecessary concern. If you still paranoid about it `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: Date())` this will never fail

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easier:

```
 datePicker.maximumDate = date.addingTimeInterval(604800)
```

604800 seconds are 7 days.

Comment: As an explain on [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1948745-addingtimeinterval) this solution does not take into account complexities like daylight saving time, etc. Depending on your project's needs, `addingTimeInterval()` may or may not be a good fit.