# How to set a minimum date to particular for date picker swift 4?

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

In swift 4, I have two textFields to set start day and end day and want to set "end day" picker the default is "start day" date and limit set the date which is earlier.

I can save start day's value from picker (datePick.date) and reference [How to set a maximum date for date picker swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004269/how-to-set-a-maximum-date-for-date-picker-swift-4) to set `datePick.minimumDate = startDay`.

The picker default date is "start day" but it can set earlier day.
I don't know how to change following code to limit it.

```
var sevenDaysfromNow: Date {
   return (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date(), options: [])!
}
```

Is there possiable to set a minimum date to particular for date picker swift 4?

[update try to use Roy Bernal code]

```
func creatEndPicker(){
//...
let daysToSubtract = 10
        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        dateComponent.day = daysToSubtract
        let earlierDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: start_Day)
        datePick.maximumDate = earlierDate 
        datePick.minimumDate = startDay 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it programmatically like Andy told you, with the picker view delegate, for instance you can put the next lines of code to get it, in your viewDidLoad or wherever you want to use the functionality:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date // use date only
        let currentDate = NSDate()  //get the current date
        myDatePicker.minimumDate = currentDate  //set the current date/time as a minimum
        myDatePicker.date = currentDate //defaults to current time but shows how to use it.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. It can be successfully for set the particular date for date picker minimum date. But it cannot limit user to set earlier date.

Comment: So If I understand you well, I think you can do it, first get the current date and then you can subtract one day to your current date, something like this:

let daysToSubtract = -1
        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        dateComponent.day = daysToSubtract
        
        let earlierDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: date!) //this var date it's your currentDate

Comment: Hi Roy Bernal, i try to use your recommend (the code is on update information) , it doesn't work . is there any mistake to code?

Comment: I think if you want to subtract, your variable must have the value:

let daysToSubtract = -10

Comment: So the thing that you want to do is, validate a minimumDate as the current date and maximumDate as 10 days after current date, isn't?

Comment: i want the function is minimumDate as the day define by user and maximumDate as 10 days after define by user.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard once you have a UIDatePicker on the screen, in the panel on the right in the attributes inspector you can check "Minimum Date" and set the minimum date there. I am sure this can also be done programmatically in which you may need to use the picker view delegate, but you should be fine doing it in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for recommend.Maybe it will be successful to set it. But I use date picker by code.`textField.inputView = datePick`